How to conditionally display field in table within visualforce page
I'm sure this will be easy for someone out there, but i just can't figure out how to get this to work. I believe I need to use render, but I'm not sure of the code. I have a visualforce page that will be used to generate and attach a pdf. In the piece of the table shown below, I only want the field 'Attended explained' to display if the field above (Ever attended in the past?) equals 'Yes'. Is there a way to conditionally display this field based upon the answer of another field. Thanks in advance!
<tr><th>Ever attended in the past?</th>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!Screen__c.Attended__c}"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr><th>Attended explained?</th>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!Screen__c.Attended_explain__c}"/></td>
    </tr>


This question is similar to: Visualforce Conditionally Render 2 Different Fields based on 2 conditions. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I previously saw that post and was unable to get that code to work with what I had above. I was hoping someone could help.

Please [edit] your post to show your VF code with the conditional formula.
